# Verify Facebook Like using Javascript/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, api

I've done my research on trying to find an answer but yet to find anything that will work for what I'm trying to do. I need either a Facebook API or some kind of Javascript.

The concept:

1. User logins into website
2. User clicks on add fan pages
3. 30 displayed pages with come up running off a point system
4. Add page #1 and get 5 points

I need to somehow verify weather or not the (user) actually likes the page. Once liked it will reward +5 points to their account.

I would like to stay away from using Facebook API. I've read multiple posts on this and nothing has really stuck out.. Here is an example of how/could work (http://add2friends.com/fb.html) . It verifies the like, but how would I get it so it could reward a point.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Note that granting rewards for social actions is against Facebook policies. "You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels." Without knowing more, just a warning that this may fall in that realm.

Comment: good practice here is to accept the best answer as a sign of appreciation and to help other users to be able to find the best answer quicker

Comment: the policy is here AND says you can incentivize users... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/ (within limits of course and done correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to do some functions to add your 5 points thing when the user clicked on the like button, which you need to define with the id of the page.

```
$('.fb-like').click(function(){
    // do the 5 points thing depending on $('.fb-like').attr('id');
})
```

The FB API would be way better though (more accurate) and really is not that hard to understand. The problem with the jquery solution is that people could endlessly click on the like button and gain points. You'd have to prevent it by storing the click in a database and validating every click.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        // do the 5 points thing, depending on the var 'response'
    }
);
```

> edge.create: fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The
>   response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was
>   liked

code from [facebooks documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).
Hope that helps!

Comment: The only issue i'm afraid of running into using facebook api is having too many calls and having facebook shut/suspend the token. We will have lots of traffic is there a way to do it without facebook?

Comment: I hardly doubt you'll have so many likes that you'll get an API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS error from the fb api. They are used to quite a big load. I suggest you just try it and if it happens you can look for alternatives. Other than this there's just the click-handler method with jquery I mentioned above. I also edited my answer to show you why the fb api is better!

Comment: Danontheline - do you do freelance on side?

Comment: Basically yes, but I'm involved in a bigger project for a while already and will stick there for the near future, so I only do smaller side-projects in case you need some quick help.